# A irregular pentagon and measuring its area.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

[image]

I found this question from another user account.  Here angle A, B,C = 120. If i construct AD and AC.  Then AD and AC are equal? If equal then how?  If we add EB then EAB are isosceles triangle. And the area of these isosceles triangle became 2sin120. Anybody please tell me where did i mistake or how to progress. Thank you.

Comment: Area of AED and ABC are equal and they are congruent.

Comment: Let $M$ be the midpoint of the diagonal $BE$. Draw lines from $M$ to all the other vertices so that you have 5 triangles. Show that all the angles of these triangles are 30, 60 or 90, and then you can easily work out the area.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis sir how to show that angles are 60 ?

Comment: I suppose the easiest would be to actually first draw $M$ by constructing $DCM$ as an equilateral triangle, then show that $DME$ and $BMC$ are also equilateral triangles (they have two equal sides with a 60 degree angle inbetween). From this you then deduce that $M$ is the midpoint of $EB$. My previous comment did this the other way around, which is a bit harder to prove.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

By considering the angles of the polygon and the position of the midpoint of $BE$ we have that such pentagon can be decomposed into an equilateral triangle with side length $2$ and three equilateral triangles with side length $\sqrt{3}$, so its area is $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\left(2^2+3\cdot \sqrt{3}^2\right)=\frac{13}{4}\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: FYI: Someone has [posted a separate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4473587/409) requesting clarification of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Equality of $AD$ and $AC$ following from the facts $AE=AB$ and $ED=BC$ (use
Pythagoras' Theorem)

Hints to compute the area:
Let $\angle ADE$ be $\theta$. Also let $BC=CD=DE=x$.
Using [sine rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) in $\triangle AED$, we get $\frac{\sin\theta}{2}=\frac{\cos\theta}{x}$ (or simply, $\tan\theta=\frac{2}{x}$).

After marking some angles and using sine rule in $\triangle ADC$, we get $$\frac{\sin(2\theta-60)}{x}=\frac{\sin(120-\theta)}{\sqrt{2^2+x^2}}$$
which is same as $\sin(2\theta-60)=\sin(120-\theta)\cos\theta$.
Solving this and using the answers would give the area.